# load a function from jquery defined from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this but it give me an undefined function

```
$(function () {
 function Test(){
   Test1();

}
 Test1();


});
```

external.js

```
$(function () {

function Test1(){
  alert("HI");
}

});
```

how can I avoid the `Test1() is undefined` error ??

Comment: Are you including external js first? If yes, then this won't get undefined.

Comment: Make it globally scoped e.g. `window.Test1 = function(){...`

Comment: include the `external.js` file.

Comment: yes of course <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js" ></script>

Comment: @RobSchmuecker That's global, OP is using ready handler...

Comment: why you put Test1 function in on load function ?

Comment: That's not closure. That's ready handler...

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak i don't know if what i wrote is the right syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function globally:

```
$(function () {
    window.Test = function(){
       Test1();
    }

    Test1();

});
```

also make sure `Test1`has been defined somewhere else!

Comment: I think `window` is not neccessary here `window.Test`.

Comment: it is! otherwise it's not in the global scope!

Answer (score 0):

Your "Test1" function is local to a anonymous function, cannot be visible outside that function. So you need put "Test1"'s definition global.

```
function Test1() {
  //...
}
```

Don't put this in another function or

```
window.Test1 = function() {
  //...
}
```

Comment: how ? you defined it as global ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change you external.js file from

```
$(function () {

function Test1(){
  alert("HI");
}

});
```

to

```
function Test1(){
  alert("HI");
}
```

it has no sense to wrapping Test1 function into on-load

Comment: has sense to not pollute the global namespace though imho